# Possible to remove Achilles skin adhesions after significant time?

Tags: dermatology, post-surgical, incision

I ruptured my right Achilles tendon in a martial arts class in late May, 2012. It was a full rupture, and surgically repaired within a week by a reputable orthopedic surgeon (Consultant/surgeon for professional sports teams).

Therapy took 1 year before I was fully cleared for jumping activities (Cleared mid June, 2013), but I healed very well and regained full use, mobility and range of motion. Recently, however, I noticed a small bit of adhesion in the skin (It puckers slightly at the base of the original incision towards the ankle when I plantar flex).

I don't think that this is anything that I need worry about, as I would expect any complications would have shown up before this, but is there anything I can do to release the adhesion?

Comment: I'm wondering if this falls into "personal medical advice" and should be reformatted. I'm inclined to answer this kind of question with, "go see a doctor".

Comment: @DaveL - I can see how that could be interpreted, but it's a general enough situation that I think it could be useful.